# SQL: join on best string match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a string "identifier", that I want to match on a "group" table, finding the "best match" (that is: the match that contains the longer part of string).
For instance: assume that I have two groups: "19" and "19.10". What I want is:

- `item "19.10.1" is part of the group "19.10"`
- `item "19.10.xxxx" is part of the group "19.10"`
- `item "19.20" is part of the group "19"`

What I got till now is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Items i
LEFT JOIN MyGroup g ON g.Prefix = SUBSTRING(i.ItemID,1,LEN(g.Prefix))
```

that matches all the string, but I don't know how can I filter the "best match" (i.e. the longer match) from my results.

By the way, I'm working on SQL Server 2005.

Example SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a9d8/1

Comment: 1) Can you change the structure of your group table? It might be helpful to be able to split the GroupDesc up in advance, or to add a "score" column. 2) You may want to look into the [PARSENAME](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) function, which may be helpful for grabbing bits of your object IDs, depending on their exact specification.

Comment: Yes, I can add a "score" column ...but I can't understand how this could help in my case. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one.

```
SELECT t.ItemID, g1.prefix, g1.GroupDesc
FROM Items i1
LEFT JOIN MyGroup g1 ON g1.Prefix = SUBSTRING(i1.ItemID,1,LEN(g1.Prefix))

RIGHT JOIN 

(

    SELECT i2.ItemID, max(len(g2.prefix)) AS ln 
    FROM Items i2
    LEFT JOIN MyGroup g2 ON g2.Prefix = SUBSTRING(i2.ItemID,1,LEN(g2.Prefix))
    GROUP BY i2.ItemID

)  t ON i1.ItemID = t.ItemID AND len(g1.prefix) = t.ln
```

You can test it on this test data:

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.MyGroup
        (GroupDesc VARCHAR(100),
         Prefix VARCHAR(10) );
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Items
        (ItemDesc VARCHAR(100),
         ItemID VARCHAR(10) );

    INSERT INTO MyGroup (GroupDesc, Prefix)
    VALUES ( 'Group A', '19' );
    INSERT INTO MyGroup (GroupDesc, Prefix)
    VALUES ( 'Group B', '19.10' );
    INSERT INTO MyGroup (GroupDesc, Prefix)
    VALUES ( 'Group C', '19.10.3' );

    INSERT INTO Items (ItemDesc, ItemID)
    VALUES ( 'Item 1', '19.10.4' );
    INSERT INTO Items (ItemDesc, ItemID)
    VALUES ( 'Item 2', '19.10.3' );
    INSERT INTO Items (ItemDesc, ItemID)
    VALUES ( 'Item 3', '19.20' );
    INSERT INTO Items (ItemDesc, ItemID)
    VALUES ( 'Item 4', '44.55' );
```

Comment: peter: thanks. This works fine. I just wonder if the query can be "optimized" storing the length of the Prefix in the groups table (as suggested in the comments above)

Comment: @Nova Yes, if you store the length of the prefix in the groups table, the query will get simpler because you will get rid of LEN(g1.Prefix) and LEN(g2.Prefix) and will replace them with something like g1.len and g2.len.

Comment: @Nova Yeah, that's what I was getting at with my suggestion -- effectively, if you store a "score" for each prefix length in the groups table, life gets a lot easier, as you can just see which match has the highest score to select the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
with tmp as
(
  SELECT * FROM Items i
  LEFT JOIN MyGroup g ON g.Prefix = SUBSTRING(i.ItemID,1,LEN(g.Prefix)) 
)
SELECT a.* FROM tmp a WHERE LEN(a.prefix) = (SELECT MAX(LEN(b.prefix)) FROM tmp b WHERE a.itemid = b.itemid )
```

Seems to work...

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a9d8/33)

Comment: @peter.petrov Perhaps I didn't quite understand what you wanted. I made some changes, is it OK now?

Comment: No, I am not the OP. Now your query is better except it does not return anything for 'Item 4' from my test data. But it's better now, yes.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were the OP, should it return `item 4` if it has no match?

Comment: xpy: thanks. Your first query was not doing what I needed: this version is much better. My idea was to update the group the Item belongs to, so maybe not returning Item4 is not a big deal...